# Property then does not exist on type boolean even if using Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm converting some Javascript code to Typescript and I'm getting an error: `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'boolean'.ts(2339)`

I have Typescript file account.tsx which:

1. checks a Firestore database to see if the user account exists,
2. if no (this mean the user exists in Firebase Auth but no entry exists in the Firestore database)
3. then create a new entry

### account.tsx

User landing page after they log in.

```js
... 
useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      uidProfileExists(user.uid)
        .then((exists: boolean) => {  // ERROR: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'boolean'.ts(2339)
          if (!exists) {
            createNewUserProfile(user)
          }
        })
        .then(() =>
          getUserProfile(user.uid).then((profileData) =>
            setProfile(profileData)
          )
        )
    }
  }, [])
```

### accountUtils.js

API calls.

```js
export async function uidProfileExists(id) {
  const userDataRef = doc(firebaseStorage, FIREBASE_DB_NAME, id)
  const docSnap = await getDoc(userDataRef)
  return Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(docSnap.exists()))
}
```

I saw solutions in other questions that said toe wrap the return in a Promise which I do here.  But the error still persists.

*IMPORTANT: This code is actually valid and runs as intended.  The error only shows when I attempt to build a prod cut.  This is a TypeError and still executes.*

Could this be an issue that one file is Javascript and the other is Typescript?  I would convert the Javascript file to Typescript but the whole file is large and I'm not yet ready to convert it.

Comment: `return Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(docSnap.exists()))` whats this? `return docSnap.exists()`

Comment: like tkausl said you sould just return `docSnap.exists()` because async functions already return a promise if the error still presists try reloading vs code or re configure ts config

Comment: I tried both with the Promise and with just the `return docSnap.exists()` with the same result.  The TypeError persists.